# Ant - Run a Build.xml for all subdirectories

Tags: ant, build, target

I have a build.xml sitting at the top level and I want the script to run a target for each subdirectory and pass in the subdirectory name as a parameter to the ANT target.

Can you help ?/??

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean under "script": bat, sh, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task. From that page:

```
    <project name="subant" default="subant1">
        <property name="build.dir" value="subant.build"/>
        <target name="subant1">
            <subant target="">
                <property name="build.dir" value="subant1.build"/>
                <property name="not.overloaded" value="not.overloaded"/>
                <fileset dir="." includes="*/build.xml"/>
            </subant>
        </target>
    </project>
```

> *this snippet build file will run ant in each subdirectory of the project directory, where a file called build.xml can be found. The property build.dir will have the value subant1.build in the ant projects called by subant.*

Answer (score 2):

this is might be what you looking for,

put this as one of your target in your parent build.xml

```
<target name="executeChildBuild">

    <ant antfile="sub1/build.xml" target="build" />
    <ant antfile="sub2/build.xml" target="build" />

</target>
```

Comment: Not quite, I want one top-level build.xml to iterate through all sub-directories and run a target method in the top level build.xml taking in the sub directory name as a paramter. The sub-directories will not have separate build.xmls.

Comment: do you meant something like, pseudo code : 
<iterate directory name>
    <ant antcall="doSomething" parameter="${directoryName}" />
</iterate>

Comment: I have made some progress, I'd like to use Subant but have an issue :

<target name="run">
    <subant target="buildcomponent" genericantfile="./build.xml">
        <dirset dir="." includes="*"/>
    </subant>
</target>

I want to set a property each time it runs which is set to the directory name, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do it in ant build file, you could use [Ant Contrib's **for** task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) to iterate over list of subdirectories and execute ant task for each of them.

```
<for param="subdir">
  <dirset dir="${build.dir}">
    <include name="./**"/>
  </dirset>
  <sequential>
    <subant target="${target}">
      <property name="subdir.name" value="@{subdir}"/>
    </subant>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

I didn't test this code since don't have ant installed, but it is close to what you're trying to do I suppose.

Comment: I have made some progress, I'd like to use Subant but have an issue :

<target name="run">
    <subant target="buildcomponent" genericantfile="./build.xml">
        <dirset dir="." includes="*"/>
    </subant>
</target>

I want to set a property each time it runs which is set to the directory name, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If I read the question correctly, this may be what you are looking for instead.

So for your example...

```
<target name="do-all">
    <antcall target="do-first">
       <param name="dir-name" value="first"/>
       <param name="intented-target" value="init"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="do-first">
        <param name="dir-name" value="second"/>
        <param name="intented-target" value="build"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="do-first">
        <param name="dir-name" value="third"/>
        <param name="intented-target" value="compile"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
<target name="do-first">
    <echo>Hello from ${dir-name} ${intented-target}</echo>
    <ant antfile="${dir-name}/build.xml" target="${intented-target}"/> 
</target>
```

When you are calling this from Ant, you would enter this at the command line:

`ant do-all`

and your output should look like this:

`do-all:`

`do-first:`

`[echo] Hello from first init`

`do-first:`

`[echo] Hello from second build`

`do-first:`

`[echo] Hello from third compile`

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL`
`Total time: 1 second`

You will of course need to make sure that the directory name that you are using as a param actually exists, or the build will fail.

You can also always feed the variable that you want to use by adding the value to the build.properties file.