# How do you create a classpath in ANT that includes all jars in a directory and it's subdirectories

Tags: ant

I'm using ANT to build a Java project that has dependency jars during compile time.  The dependency jars are nested inside a directory.  What this means is, the directory contains sub-directories (which might contain sub-directories) and jars as well.

I want to create an ANT  element to include all the jars inside the directory.  Below is my code but doesn't work.  I'm wondering if this can't be done in ANT or I'm doing something wrong:

```
<path id="javaee.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${javaee.modules.dir}">
        <patternset>
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </patternset>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098463/ant-run-a-build-xml-for-all-subdirectories

Comment: The link you provided talks about an Ant task that would run other build.xml files in subdir which isn't what I'm looking for.  I would like Ant to just recursively traverse the sub dirs and include any jar to the path.